# Constraint pattern in module config Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, design-patterns

Is it possible to set a constraint pattern to only numbers and a &amp?

So I could make a url like: `localhost/cms/user/multipledelete/1&2`

I have the following config right now, but it only allows numbers. I want that an `ID` can be numbers and &amp.

Here is my code:

```
'route'    => '/user[/:action][/:id][/sort/:order_by][/:order][/page/:page]',
   'constraints' => array(
   'action' => '(?!\bsort\b)(?!\bpage\b)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
   'id'     => '[0-9]+',
   'order_by' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
   'order' => 'asc|desc',
   'page' => '[0-9]+',
 ),
```

Comment: for which field you want string like this. specify.

Comment: For `id` I want numbers like 7 or as I said 7&8. So I can give more numbers with a &amp or something. I've checkboxes with id-numbers, so I want to give them with my url and make it possible to delete more users.

Comment: I have posted the answer. It will work for you sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

```
[0-9&]+
```

Like:

```
'constraints' => array(
   'action' => '(?!\bsort\b)(?!\bpage\b)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
   'id'     => '[0-9&]+',
   'order_by' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
   'order' => 'asc|desc',
   'page' => '[0-9]+',
),
```

Comment: read this: https://qualysguard.qualys.com/qwebhelp/fo_help/module_pc/policies/regular_expression_symbols.htm